# How to create a permanent login from jupyter notebook to github with ssh_rsa key pair

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, ssh-keys, amazon-sagemaker

So my question is this,

When creating a notebook in `Sagemaker` `AWS` I need to help the devEngineer keep his secret key in `.ssh/id_rsa` as the file after every instance reboot becomes empty. 
He requires a `github` repo to be downloaded and he has to work on the code and then push the updates as needed. 
Please let me know what details I need to provide to help you help me. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the filesystems for my notebook instance:

```
sh-4.2$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G   76K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1   94G   76G   19G  81% /
/dev/nvme1n1     99G   40G   55G  43% /home/ec2-user/SageMaker
```

Note that one pointing to `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker` is the only one which is saved between reboots. Since ssh keys are stored in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh`, they are lost after reboot.

The way I make it work is:

1. Create the folder `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/.ssh`
2. Run `ssh-keygen` and set the location `/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/.ssh/id_rsa`
3. Clone repo with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/SageMaker/.ssh/id_rsa -F /dev/null" git clone git@domain:account/repo.git`
4. cd repo
5. Set your repo to use the custom location with `git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/SageMaker/.ssh/id_rsa -F /dev/null"`

Based on https://superuser.com/a/912281

Comment: It does not work for me. I have a user /home/sagemaker-user/ and have my key in .ssh/id_rsa. Anything else am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Notebook Instance had launched a new feature few months ago which allows you to associate git repositories with your Notebook Instances.

Please take a look at this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-now-support-git-integration-for-increased-persistence-collaboration-and-reproducibility/) and [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html) on how to use this feature. Let us know if this works for your use case.